# Which function is triggered on options change in a question which is dependent on choices from another question

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

Details codes and description is inside this ticket.

https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/ticket/details/t12060/which-function-is-triggered-on-options-change-in-a-question-which-is-dependent-on

It does not work in ```
"survey-angular": "^1.9.48",
Code
version 1

It works fine in v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed up with you in your Help Desk thread: https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/ticket/details/t12060/which-function-is-triggered-on-options-change-in-a-question-which-is-dependent-on.

If you have any more questions or need any further assistance, feel free to ask.